# Branch Test/Live links not working as expected

Tags: ios, branch.io

I've got an iOS app which uses deep linking. I'm using Branch.io for the linking and it's working as expected on Android. On iOS, I'm having a really odd problem, which has only appeared since I deployed the app on Testflight.

App not installed:

- Takes me to a defined website as expected.
- When downloading the app from Testflight, the app opens with the deep linked data - as expected.

App installed:

- The link opens in Safari to the website as mentioned above (only in iOS 11.3+)
- Opening the app after this, the app opens with the deep linked data - but why hasn't the app opened?
- Opening one of the links from the Test section of the Branch Dashboard opens the app, doesn't open Safari at all.

The app, as is on Testflight and run locally with Debug enabled, have the same bundle identifiers/URI schemes/prefixes. It's also working as expected on a device running iOS 9.3.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is Deepti from Branch. This seems like a setup issue. This is what I would recommend:

1. Make sure your Link Settings are configured for iOS as mentioned in [this doc](https://docs.branch.io/pages/dashboard/integrate/). Be sure that the URI scheme and bundle identifiers exactly match between your Branch dashboard and info.plist file.
2. Put breakpoints on each of these lifecycle events: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, open url, userActivity and didReceiveRemoteNotification and hit the Branch link to see whether each of these is getting triggered from scratch. If they aren't then there revisiting the setup might help.

I hope this helps. If you need further assistance, please write to integrations@branch.io with the details and we would be happy to help.